# Issue with missing DLLs and references

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reference

I'm trying to cut out an MVC project from a greater solution, since the solution was getting too big, and I wanted to cut it into smaller pieces. However, this seems to be a more difficult task than expected.

I can easily just copy-paste the project out, and create a new solution with this one project, I do seem to have some issues with the references however. None of my references seem to contain a path (*many of these references were project references, but I just need to reference the DLLs*).

Here's an image of the solutions explorer:
[image]

I'm not sure what's going on, or how to fix it. I've tried a few things like removing a reference, and then re-adding it, but to no avail.

I haven't seen this issue before, I can't seem to find a solution, nor find any good documentation online.

Comment: Sometime this happens when a Higher .Net Version of DLL is referred by a lower .Net Version Project.

Answer (score 4):

Please copy the package.config file from the old project into the newly created project and then go to Package Manager console (Visual Studio, Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console): 
Command:"**nuget restore**"
so that your all dependency get restored.
**"(many of these references were project references, but I just need to reference the DLLs)."** for dll references you need to set the "localCopy" property to true which you will find inside your second screen you have uploaded after setting the "localCopy" value to "true" your all project references would be locally converted into dll into your bin folder.

Comment: Still getting the yellow warning triangles next to my reference names

Comment: I do have the DLL's in my `bin` folder, but I can't change this value. Every time I change focus after settings the value to true, it goes back to false.

Comment: Now you can do one thing that remove each  references one by one and reinstall.

Comment: Tried that as well, doesn't work either. Still the references have no path on them, and I suspect that this might be the reason, since the project have no idea where to look for these references. I just don't know why the path isn't added to the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the designated project or class library, ensuring that no errors are present. It's important to note that there is a 50% chance of encountering compilation errors that could prevent the generation of the .dll file. This precautionary measure ensures the successful generation of the .dll file and contributes to the overall stability and functionality of the project or library.